# Angular 7 component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular7

I need to pass an array named "photos" from my component.ts to component.html. Here is my component.ts file

```
export class PhotosComponent implements OnInit {
public photos:any[]
constructor(){}
ngOnInit(){

 S3.listObjects({Delimiter: '/'}, function(err, data) {

  var albumName
if (err) {
  return alert('There was an error listing your albums: ' + err.message);
} else {
    console.log(data.CommonPrefixes)

  var albums = data.CommonPrefixes.map(function(commonPrefix) {
   //   console.log(albums)
    var prefix = commonPrefix.Prefix;
    console.log(prefix)
    albumName = decodeURIComponent(prefix.replace('/', ''));
    console.log(albumName)
    this.photos.push(albumName)
  });

  }


});
console.log(this.photos)

}
```

At line this.photos.push(albumName), it says " Cannot read property 'photos' of undefined" Also I am not able to pass data to html. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Your `this` has a different scope, because you are in a callback function. The easiest way to fix this is to use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) instead.

Change `function(err, data)` to `(err, data) =>` and `function(commonPrefix)` to `(commonPrefix) =>`.

Another (old) solution would be to bind `this` to the function or to store `this` in a different local variable.

Comment: This resolved my problem. Thanks for the answer. However, it started throwing the same error for 'push'. Do you have any suggestions how can I fix that as well? "Cannot read property 'push' of undefined"

Comment: sure. you are only defining the variable `photos`, but you never assign a value to it. you could initialize it right at the declaration by changing the line to `public photos:any[] = [];` - this means it's initialized with an empty array.

Comment: That fixed the error but this.photos.push(albumName) is not pushing the albumnames to the array. It's still empty. Only if I do this.photos = albumName, pass the last albumname to the value. I need to pass the whole array of albumanames. Any suggestions

Comment: I resolved the issue myself. I was calling the array before it finishes pushing the names to it. Thanks for your help